# How can I add the latest data from xlsx to Kivy app?

Tags: python, database, kivy, kivy-language

I am designing an application using kivy for my final year project. The layout of the application is already done, and I wish to add the latest data from the xlsx database. The data should be updated whenever a new data is added to the database and only the latest data should be shown in the designated column. The application is to monitor hospital gases real time. The values from pressure transducers and flowmeters are collected by arduino and sent to NodeMCU which transmits this data to the xlsx database.

For example, in the application, under cylinder pressure, the application should draw the latest value from the xlsx database and present it on screen. Only one value should be displayed and that value should get updated each time a new value enters the database under cylinder pressure.

I hope I can get an answer soon and thanks in advance. I have done the program in Pycharm. Hope someone helps.

Cheerss!!!

Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pandas as pd
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty

class Data():
    def base(self):
        data= pd.read_excel("HelloWorld.xlsx")
        df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Hello'])





class MainWindow(Screen):
    Read = Data()
    Data.base(Read)
    def setup(self):
        self.read= str(self.Read)




class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("mymain.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

mymain.kv

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"


    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Cylinder Duration"
            font_size: 45


        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Current Cylinder"
                font_size: 45


            Label:
                text:"Cylinder Pressure"
                font_size: 45

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label :
                text:"1"
                font_size: 50

            Label:
                id: labe1
                text:"1203"
                font_size: 50
        Button:
            text: "Flow"
            font_size: 50
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"




<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Label:
        id:central
        text:"CENTRALISED \n SUPPLY "
        font_size: 25
        text_size: 19, 550
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.03, 'center_y':0.48}
        canvas:
            Line:

                width: 2
                points: (self.x+40, self.y-120,self.x+40,self.y+700)
            Color:
                rgb: (0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9)

    Button:
        text: "Back"
        size_hint:1,0.05
        pos_hint:{"top":1}
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



    Button:
        id: btn2
        text:"ICU"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"top":0.95}
        size_hint: 0.2,0.19

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.056, "top": 0.885}
        size_hint:0.745,0.05
        background_normal:''
        Color: if (labe1 <= 1230)
                background_color= '#DC143C'
            else
                background_color=(0,0,1,1)




    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.06, "top":0.91 }
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.14, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.18, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.22, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.26, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.3, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.34, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.38, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.42, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.46, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.54, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.58, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.62, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.66, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.74, "top": 0.91}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Button:
        text:"OT"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"top":0.76}
        size_hint: 0.2,0.19

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.056, "top": 0.69}
        size_hint:0.745,0.05
        background_color: (0,0,1,1)
        background_normal:''
        background_down:'#DC143C'
        on_press: self.background_color='#DC143C'
        on_release: self.background_color=0,0,1,1
    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.06, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.14, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.18, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.22, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.26, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.3, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.34, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.38, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.42, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.46, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.54, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.58, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.62, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.66, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.74, "top": 0.715}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'



    Button:
        text:"WARDS"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"top":0.57}
        size_hint: 0.2,0.19

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.056, "top": 0.5}
        size_hint:0.745,0.05
        background_color: (0,0,1,1)
        background_normal:''
        background_down:'#DC143C'
        on_press: self.background_color='#DC143C'
        on_release: self.background_color=0,0,1,1
    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.06, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.14, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.18, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.22, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.26, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.3, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.34, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.38, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.42, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.46, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.54, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.58, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.62, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.66, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.74, "top": 0.525}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Button:
        text:"CCU"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"top":0.38}
        size_hint: 0.2,0.19

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.056, "top": 0.315}
        size_hint:0.745,0.05
        background_color: (0,0,1,1)
        background_normal:''
        background_down:'#DC143C'
        on_press: self.background_color='#DC143C'
        on_release: self.background_color=0,0,1,1
    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.06, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.14, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.18, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.22, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.26, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.3, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.34, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.38, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.42, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.46, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.54, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.58, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.62, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.66, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.74, "top": 0.34}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Button:
        text:"HDU"
        pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"top":0.19}
        size_hint: 0.2,0.19

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.056, "top": 0.12}
        size_hint:0.745,0.05
        background_color: (0,0,1,1)
        background_normal:''
        background_down:'#DC143C'
        on_press: self.background_color='#DC143C'
        on_release: self.background_color=0,0,1,1
    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.06, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.1, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.14, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.18, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.22, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.26, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.3, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.34, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.38, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.42, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.46, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.5, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'


    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.54, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.58, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.62, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.66, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.7, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'

    Image:
        size_hint: 0.05,0.1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.74, "top": 0.145}
        source: 'right-arrow.png'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site to dig through your code. And we're _definitely_ not going to download your code from Google Drive.